# How to parallelize JUnit tests?

Tags: junit, parallel-processing

I currently have a couple of tests which really run very long. Inside each test I do always the same:

there is a loop which creates a new object (every iteration with different parameters), does some time consuming calculations with the object and at the end of each iteration compares the result to the expected result.

Every iteration in this loop is completely isolated. I could easily run all those 200 very time consuming iterations in parallel. But how best to do this?

Cheers,
AvH

Answer (score 0):

Junit 4 has inbuilt parellel processing. Check this [documentation](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/07/06/running-junit-tests-parallel-maven).

Apart from that you may need consider moving all the duplicate iterations in to a static setup method and annotate as @BeforeClass. That will make sure code runs only once in the entire lifecycle.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
     //Move anything needs to run only once.
}
```

Comment: Parallel processing is a Maven feature and not a JUnit feature.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an own modification of the [Parameterized runner](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html). See http://jankesterblog.blogspot.de/2011/10/junit4-running-parallel-junit-classes.html

Comment: Thanks! I have a few questions:

Comment: 1. your first link says, that "Tests with single parameter" allow to return Object[]. In my case this always throws an error saying: "must return an Iterable of arrays."
If I wrap the parameters in an anditional array it works.

Comment: You need JUnit 4.12 for "Tests with single parameter". I assume you are using 4.11.

Comment: Strange things I noticed:
1. A BeforeClass-annotated static setup() method is called AFTER the Parameters-annotated data() method. Is this expected?

2. I do some System.out and System.err calls in my Test-annotated method. In my experiments it shows that for 5 Parameters the Test-annotated method is not actually called 5 times. The printout shows that it is called somewhere between 7..11 times, meaning some tests are executed twice. What is going on here?

Comment: Maybe this is just an artifact as how System.out and System.err work? Maybe Test is only executed 5 times and the printout is wrong? I used System.out.flush() and System.err.flush() without solving the multiple printout.

Comment: The Parameterized runner runs your test exactly once for each data set.

Answer (score 0):

The library [JUnit Toolbox](https://github.com/michaeltamm/junit-toolbox) provides a [ParallelParameterized](https://michaeltamm.github.io/junit-toolbox/com/googlecode/junittoolbox/ParallelParameterized.html) runner.